# How to create dynamic array of DateTime?

Tags: .net, arrays, delphi-prism, oxygene

I need to create a dynamic array of DateTime, but I don't know before hand how many dates I will have to add. I did experiment with ArrayList, but it doesn't help.

So, how do you create dynamic array of DateTime in Delphi Prism?

Is this how you do it?

```
mydates: array of DateTime;
```

**UPDATE 1**

I did the following and compiler says that there is no overloaded set_BoldedDates with these parameters."

```
  mydates:ArrayList;
  mydates := new ArrayList;
  mydates.Add(new DateTime(2012,11,23));

  DataCalendar.BoldedDates := mydates; //also I did mydates.ToArray caused error.
```

The above code only works if I set the mydates as follows:

```
const
mydates : Array[0..1] of DateTime = [new DateTime(2012,11,23), new Datetime(2012,11,13)];
```

Thanks,

Comment: `List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();`  Does delphi not have generics?

Comment: @LarsTech, Yes and that would be ArrayList in Delphi Prism or TList in Delphi, but I need array of DateTime. If I do `mydates: array of DateTime`, it complier raises an error.

Comment: What's the background story on why ArrayList doesn't help?

Comment: @LarsTech :) I am using an usercontrol, Month Calendar, that I found on the Internet. It has a property called BoldedDates, which only accepts array of datetime. It won't allow me to set ArrayList for array of DateTime.

Comment: Obviously I don't know Delphi.  Wouldn't a .ToArray() work on the ArrayList or TList?

Comment: One last shot: ArrayList is a list of objects, so the method is probably choking on that.  If TList<DateTime> is equivalent to List<DateTime>, then try using the ToArray() on the TList, since it should return an array of DateTimes.

Comment: @LarsTech, I don't have access to TList. I am using Delphi-Prism Visual Studio 2010 for .NET. So, I can only use ArrayList.

Comment: @LarsTech: Delphi Prism is the .NET version of Delphi, and it has access to the standard .NET data types (including generics, which aren't needed here - a standard array of System.DateTime works fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me, and displays the dates properly. (**Note:** there is no error handling for parsing errors or out of range dates! This is strictly designed to show the use of the `array of DateTime` with `MonthCalendar.BoldedDates` in Delphi Prism.)

```
method MainForm.button2_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
var
  Dt: array of System.DateTime;
  TheSize: Int32;
begin
  TheSize := Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

  Dt := new System.DateTime[TheSize];
  for i: Int32 := 0 to TheSize - 1 do
    Dt[i] := new DateTime(2012, 11, i + 4);

  monthCalendar1.BoldedDates := Dt;  
end;
```

A test entering `5` in the textbox shows this result:

[image: Sample display of bolded dates]

Comment: Ken, Although I am not using .NET month calendar but a third-party usercontrol that I found on the internet, BoldedDates property in both controls treated the same way. The only reason I am not using .NET MonthCalendar is because I can't change just the color of boldeddates or their background color to color I need to set. Anyways your answer does work as expected. Thanks.